# ALTER TABLE my_table ADD @column INT

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

If i want to use a variable as name of the new column, is this posible in MS SQL?

Example that dont work:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD @column INT
```

**This worked great for me:**

```
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE my_table ADD ' + @column + ' INT')
```

Comment: What is the error its giving?

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga: the error message is irrelevant. it's simply incorrect syntax for the ALTER TABLE statement

Comment: Sanitize you variable (@Column) before you do this... This is highly essential or you will regret later

Answer (score 20):

This is possible using dynamic sql to build your DDL and using the `EXEC` command to execute the string.

```
Declare @SQL VarChar(1000)

SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE my_table ADD ' + @column + ' INT'

Exec (@SQL)
```

See [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-dynamic-sql-part-2) article.

I will also add that the moment you venture to the land of dynamic sql, you need to take care to not expose yourself to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Always clean up the parameters coming in.

As Philip mentions - think long and hard before doing this. The fact that it is possible does not make it a good thing...

Erland Sommarskog wrote an extensive article about using dynamic sql - [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) which I recommend reading fully.

Comment: Also make sure the value of the variable is sanitised for errors and sql injection.

Comment: ...but its not a particularly good idea, as you could end up with columns named with reserved words (column "column"), or (shudder) containing embedded spaces. Think long and hard before you do this!

Comment: I often find that using EXEC is the first sign that I am off in the weeds. But occassionally its the best of poor alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ([EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx))

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
        ID INT
)
GO
SELECT * FROM MyTable
GO
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(100)
SET @column = 'MyNewCol'
EXEC('ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD ' + @column + ' INT')
GO
SELECT * FROM MyTable
GO
DROP TABLE MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter procedure sp_check_table_column
(
    @field_name varchar(max),
    @data_type varchar(max),
    @mandatory varchar(max)
)
as
if not exists (select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>' and COLUMN_NAME = @field_name)
begin
 declare @sql varchar(max)
 set @sql = ('ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD ' + @field_name + ' ' + @data_type + ' ' + @mandatory)
 exec (@sql) 
end
```