# T-Sql Stored Procedure to Dynamically Add a Column to a Table Based on Parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ALTER TABLE my_table ADD @column INT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614101/alter-table-my-table-add-column-int)

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to have a stored procedure that is effectively this:

```
USE [dbname]
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[CreateColumn]
    @Table varchar(255),
    @ColumnName varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        SET ARITHABORT ON
        SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
        SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        SET ANSI_PADDING ON
        SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
    COMMIT

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ALTER TABLE [Schema].@Table ADD @ColumnName varchar(255) NULL
        ALTER TABLE [Schema].@Table SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
    COMMIT
END
GO
```

Basically, I could pass in a table name and column name and it would create it on that table with proper transactions.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm sorry, it's not possible. See this website.

I'm sorry, but that is not true.

It is, however, clumsy. You are almost as well off simply executing in-line SQL (if form client code) or simply composing an SQL statement each time, as you need to define the Table name, the Column name, The Column DataType, and the default value each time you execute (unless you hard-code some of those parameters in i.e. the column data type will ALWAYS be VarChar(255).

Play with variations on this, and see if you find what you are looking for. However, there are probably better ways to acheive what you are trying to do:

```
DECLARE @sql NChar(4000);

SET @Sql = N'ALTER TABLE [Schema].' 
    + @TableName + ' ADD ' 
    + @ColumnName + ' ' 
    + @ColumnType + ' ' 
    + @InitialValue

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
GO
```

Comment: It's not possible to do it as OP wanted, not using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, it's not possible. See [this website](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic484760-338-1.aspx).

Comment: You are technically right, I wanted to do it without dynamic SQL but now I know I can't.