# SQL Server calculate dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a given table with following structure:

```
DateAndTime             | Count Wine | Count Beer

2014-08-11 16:45:22.480 | 100        | 50

2014-08-12 16:45:22.480 | 50         | 50

2014-08-18 16:45:22.480 | 200        | 100

2014-08-19 16:45:22.480 | 300        | 200
```

What I need is a select statement with following Output:

```
---  | Week No 33 | Week No 34

Beer | 50         | 150

Wine | 75         | 250
```

So the columns (week no.) are dynamically depending on data.
And the calaculated values should be the average of the rows within the calendar week.

I have no idea how to solve this....

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614101/alter-table-my-table-add-column-int or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516696/add-column-dynamically-with-select-query or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944006/t-sql-stored-procedure-to-dynamically-add-a-column-to-a-table-based-on-parameter ?

Comment: I tried a lot, but I'm not an expert and have also syntax problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is an elegant way.. but this works.

```
create table sample 
(
dtdate smalldatetime,
cWine int,
cBeer int
)

insert into sample 
values('2014-08-11 16:45:22.480', 100 , 50),('2014-08-12 16:45:22.480', 50, 50),
('2014-08-18 16:45:22.480', 200 , 100),('2014-08-19 16:45:22.480', 300 , 200)



   DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
   select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DATEPART(WEEK,dtDate)) from sample  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')


    SELECT @query = 'SELECT Countname, '+@cols+'
FROM
(

  SELECT countName,y,Avg(CountValue)avge from 

(
SELECT countName,countValue,dtdate,DATEPART(WEEK,dtdate)as y from  sample
unpivot(
countValue for Countname in (cwine,cBeer)
)unpiv )x group by y,countName


) x
pivot
(
  sum(avge)
  for y in ('+@cols+')
) p'


execute(@query)
```

Comment: Did you read question? OP says ` the columns (week no.) are dynamically depending on data`

Comment: yes, this example is working. But the week columns are not dynamically created based on the given data;-)

Comment: You mean ..even if there are 52 weeks in a year, it should generate columns only for those weeks that have data?

Comment: yes exactly, show only this weeks that have data.
And the whole statement should be used as DB query in Excel. With current example it doesn't work. I think this is because also in Server Management Studio I get two result sets.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the countnames? E.g.
countValue for Countname in (cwine as Test,..) isn't working.

And second question, how can I mark question as answered?

Comment: In the select list, give CountName as Test [not in the countValue for Countname in (cwine...) clause]

Comment: There is a tick mark to the left side of this answer. You just have to click it to Mark as Answered

Comment: Have created sample fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e4ac/2 . is this what you are looking for?

Comment: when I add 'as Test' in the select list, the result is that first column is named Test.
What I want is to adjust names for cwine and cBeer

Comment: SELECT @query = 'SELECT Case 
 When Countname =''cBeer'' then ''TestBeer''
 When Countname = ''cWine'' then ''TestWine'' end as countname

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DATEPART(WEEK,dtdate)) 
                    from master.sample 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')



 SELECT @query = 'SELECT Countname, '+@cols+'
FROM
(

  SELECT countName,y,Avg(CountValue)avge from 

(
SELECT countName,countValue,dtdate,DATEPART(WEEK,dtdate)as y from  sample
unpivot(
countValue for Countname in (cwine,cBeer)
)unpiv )x group by y,countName


) x
pivot
(
  sum(avge)
  for y in ('+@cols+')
) p'

SELECT @query 
execute(@query)
```