# WHILE SQL Server error

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I have a SQL query like this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_dynamic_column_list](
    @tahun varchar(4),
    @bulan varchar(2),
    @pks varchar(3))
AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @totalrow int
    DECLARE @inc int = 1
    DECLARE @dynamictable NVARCHAR(MAX)

    CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
        tanggal datetime, 
    )

    -- query cari column dulu baru alter table temp diatas
    SET @totalrow = dbo.fn_count_row_penerimaan(2014,11,40)

    WHILE (@inc <= @totalrow)
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #temp ADD @inc FLOAT
        SET @inc = @inc + 1
    END

    INSERT INTO #temp 
        EXEC sp_get_list_penerimaan_pks2 @tahun, @bulan, @pks

    SELECT * FROM #temp 

    DROP TABLE #temp
END
```

I got error like this:

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@inc'.

I'm new to SQL Server and like to know the solution for this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ALTER TABLE my_table ADD @column INT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614101/alter-table-my-table-add-column-int)

You need to use Execute statement as mentioned in link.

```
WHILE @inc <= @totalrow
BEGIN
  exec ('ALTER table #temp add '+@inc+' FLOAT   set '+@inc+' = '+ @inc+'+1')
END
```

Comment: @Jsnow You have to accept this answer if it works. Just check the mark below of voting arrows

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL statment variable value cannot be provided as a column name, to achieve this you have to use a **dynamic SQL query** like the Following:

```
WHILE (@inc <= @totalrow)
BEGIN
    Declare @strquery as varchar(4000)

    SET @strquery  = 'ALTER TABLE #temp ADD [' + @inc + '] FLOAT'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @strquery  -- if @inc =1 then @strQuery : ALTER TABLE #temp ADD [1] FLOAT

    SET @inc = @inc + 1

END
```

You can read more about Dynamic SQL queries in this [Article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)